# How to send information of fragment to activity and In reverse in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

How can I send information of activity to fragment and of fragment to activity 
in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very **BAD** and **not clear**! Please before ask any question, first read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then ask question.

But for use custom method in `Activity` from `Fragment`, you can use my below example.

**First write your Method in your activity:**

```
public void showMessage(){
    Toast.makeText(context, "YOUR MESSAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Then, you should create instance of activity in your Fragment :**

```
public class YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME extends Fragment {
   private YOUR_ACTIIVTY_NAME yourActivity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        //Initialize
        mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        //Call method 
        yourActivity.showMessage();

    return view;
}
```

I hope help you.

Comment: thanks a lot Engineer for Best answer